# accessing date variable columns from library

Tags: sas

am trying assign '.' value to all date variable columns from a specific library but i can't find a way to get only the date variable column data from a certain library. any help is appreciated. 
  -->code to convert all date variables to missing-->

```
DATA assgnmiss;
        SET dtevars ;
        date=.;
        KEEP date;
    RUN;
```

sample code to access date variables-->

```
data table;
   set sashelp.vcolumn;
   where libname='Stats' and datatype ='Date';
run;
```

Comment: There is no datatype date. Do you have a way of identifying date variables? Perhaps a naming convention or a format(s) that's applied to date variables? Otherwise you can try based on searching formats but there's no guarantee it will be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Reeza has commented, SAS data set variables only come in two types: character and numeric. Either can potentially contain date information. If the creator of the dataset did not apply any date formats to their numeric date columns, all you have to go on are:

- Formats
- Labels
- Variable names containing 'date', or some other naming convention used by the creator of the data set.

Unformatted date variables are not easily distinguishable from other numeric variables. There are a couple of clues, though:

- Date variables count the number of days since 1st January 1960, so 1st January 2016 = 20454.
- Datetime variables count the number of seconds since 1st January 1960 00:00:00, so 1st January 2016 00:00:00 = 1767225600.

If you find unformatted numeric variables that have date or datetime-like distributions of values, they might well contain date information.

Character date variables are potentially harder to spot, as they might not contain information in any standard date format. If you want to attempt to automate the detection of character dates, you could try inputting them using the `anydtdtm.` informat, which catches most of the standard date and time formats, and see whether you get a missing value.

The only way to get a really definitive answer is to contact the creator of the dataset.